# Gulp watch with gulp-file-include

Tags: node.js, gulp, gulp-watch

I'm using *yeoman/generator-gulp-webapp* and I added *gulp-file-include*.
**I set up gulpfile.js to include files on build**, but I don't know how to set up **for gulp watch**.

Below is my attempt to do this, but it seems that this doesn't work. I don't get any errors. Everything works fine except index.html has @@include(...) instead a code from those files

```
'use strict';
// generated on 2014-10-27 using generator-gulp-webapp 0.1.0

var gulp = require('gulp');

// load plugins
var $ = require('gulp-load-plugins')();

gulp.task('styles', function () {
    return gulp.src('app/styles/main.scss')
        .pipe($.rubySass({
            style: 'expanded',
            precision: 10
        }))
        .pipe($.autoprefixer('last 1 version'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('.tmp/styles'))
        .pipe($.size());
});

gulp.task('fileinclude', function () {
    return gulp.src('app/*.html')
        .pipe($.fileInclude())
        .pipe($.size());
})

gulp.task('scripts', function () {
    return gulp.src('app/scripts/**/*.js')
        .pipe($.jshint())
        .pipe($.jshint.reporter(require('jshint-stylish')))
        .pipe($.size());
});

gulp.task('html', ['styles', 'scripts'], function () {
    var jsFilter = $.filter('**/*.js');
    var cssFilter = $.filter('**/*.css');

    return gulp.src(['app/*.html'])
        .pipe($.fileInclude())
        .pipe($.useref.assets({searchPath: '{.tmp,app}'}))
        .pipe(jsFilter)
        .pipe($.uglify())
        .pipe(jsFilter.restore())
        .pipe(cssFilter)
        .pipe($.csso())
        .pipe(cssFilter.restore())
        .pipe($.useref.restore())
        .pipe($.useref())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))
        .pipe($.size());
});

gulp.task('images', function () {
    return gulp.src('app/images/**/*')
        .pipe($.cache($.imagemin({
            optimizationLevel: 3,
            progressive: true,
            interlaced: true
        })))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/images'))
        .pipe($.size());
});

gulp.task('fonts', function () {
    return $.bowerFiles()
        .pipe($.filter('**/*.{eot,svg,ttf,woff}'))
        .pipe($.flatten())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/fonts'))
        .pipe($.size());
});

gulp.task('extras', function () {
    return gulp.src(['app/*.*', '!app/*.html'], { dot: true })
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});

gulp.task('clean', function () {
    return gulp.src(['.tmp', 'dist'], { read: false }).pipe($.clean());
});

gulp.task('cleanafter', function () {
    return gulp.src(['dist/*.tmp.html'], { read: false }).pipe($.clean());
});

gulp.task('build', ['html', 'images', 'fonts', 'extras']);

gulp.task('default', ['clean'], function () {
    gulp.start('build');
});

gulp.task('connect', function () {
        var connect = require('connect');
        var app = connect()
            .use(require('connect-livereload')({port: 35729}))
            .use(connect.static('app'))
            .use(connect.static('.tmp'))
            .use(connect.directory('app'));

        require('http').createServer(app)
            .listen(9000)
            .on('listening', function () {
                console.log('Started connect web server on http://localhost:9000');
            });
});

gulp.task('serve', ['connect', 'fileinclude', 'styles'], function () {
    require('opn')('http://localhost:9000');
});

// inject bower components
gulp.task('wiredep', function () {
    var wiredep = require('wiredep').stream;

    gulp.src('app/styles/*.scss')
        .pipe(wiredep({
            directory: 'app/bower_components'
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('app/styles'));

    gulp.src('app/*.html')
        .pipe(wiredep({
            directory: 'app/bower_components'
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('app'));
});

gulp.task('watch', ['connect', 'fileinclude', 'serve'], function () {
    var server = $.livereload();

    // watch for changes

    gulp.watch([
        'app/*.html',
        '.tmp/styles/**/*.css',
        'app/scripts/**/*.js',
        'app/images/**/*'
    ]).on('change', function (file) {
        server.changed(file.path);
    });

    gulp.watch('app/styles/**/*.scss', ['styles']);
    gulp.watch('app/scripts/**/*.js', ['scripts']);
    gulp.watch('app/images/**/*', ['images']);
    gulp.watch('app/*.html', ['fileinclude']);
    gulp.watch('bower.json', ['wiredep']);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one

```
`var fileinclude = require('gulp-file-include');
gulp.task('fileinclude', function() {
  gulp.src(['**/*.html'])
    .pipe(fileinclude())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
});`
```

and add the fileinclude in to the watch taks array.

```
gulp.task('watch', ['fileinclude','serve'], function () {
gulp.watch(['app/**/*'], reload);
gulp.watch('app/styles/**/*.scss', ['styles']);
gulp.watch('app/scripts/**/*.js', ['scripts']);
gulp.watch('app/images/**/*', ['images']);
gulp.watch('bower.json', ['wiredep']);
});
```

Works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in your html task:
Your first source is `*.html` all html files, then you are sending only the html files through the pipe.

If you change the source to `app/**/*` you will now get all the files.

```
gulp.task('html', ['styles', 'scripts'], function () {

  return gulp.src(['app/**/*'])
    .pipe($.fileInclude())
    .pipe($.useref.assets({searchPath: '{.tmp,app}'}))
    .pipe(jsFilter)
    .pipe($.uglify())
    .pipe(jsFilter.restore())
    .pipe(cssFilter)
    .pipe($.csso())
    .pipe(cssFilter.restore())
    .pipe($.useref.restore())
    .pipe($.useref())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))
});
```